# Child component renders even though its being memoized

Tags: reactjs

Child component renders even though props are not altered of it.
Following is the parent component

```
import Child from "./Child";

function Parent({
  selected,
  show,
  setShow,
}) {
  const [isRunNow, setIsRunNow] = useState(true);
  const [isNotifyMe, setIsNotifyMe] = useState(false);

  
  const handleNotify = useCallback(() => {
    setIsNotifyMe(!isNotifyMe);
  }, [isNotifyMe]);

  const handleSchedule = useCallback(() => {
    setIsRunNow(!isRunNow);
  }, [isRunNow]);

  const WindowForm = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <label className={styles.labelWeight}> Name : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={selected.name}
              readOnly={true}
              className={styles.input}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <label className={styles.labelWeight}>Description : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={selected.description}
              readOnly={true}
              className={styles.input}
            ></input>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="runImm"
              id="runImm"
              checked={isRunNow}
              onChange={handleSchedule}
            ></input>
            <label> Schedule as soon as possible</label>
          </Col>
          <Col span={12}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="notifyProcess"
              id="notifyProcess"
              checked={isNotifyMe}
              onChange={handleNotify}
            ></input>
            <label> Notify me when this process ends</label>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <label>Submission Notes : </label>
            <textarea
              name="notes"
              id="notes"
              rows="4"
              cols="50"
              disabled={!isNotifyMe}
            ></textarea>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <Child isRunNow={isRunNow} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={show}
      width={800}
      centered
      maskClosable={false}
      onCancel={() => setShow(false)}
      title="JKM"
      
    >
      <WindowForm />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Child component is as follows:

```
import Uploader from "./Uploader";
import Downloader from "./Downloader";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  console.log("passed here"); // THIS IS NEVER LOGGED!!
  return true;
};

function Child({ isRunNow }) {
  console.log(
    `Rendering Childe component...isRunNow value : ${isRunNow}`
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="ka">
        <TabPane tab="ka" key="ka">
           Panel
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="sa" key="sa" disabled={isRunNow}>
          <Downloader />
        </TabPane>
        <TabPane tab="da" key="da">
          <Uploader />
        </TabPane>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Child, areEqual);
```

When I check or uncheck check box Notify me, the child component **Child** re-renders every time.  It seems props are not equal and hence its re-rending. I could not figure out where its going wrong.
Please suggest where i m doing wrong.

Comment: it's happend eveytime you click checkbox named runImm?

Comment: Yes, when I check or uncheck the checkbox named notifyProcess, the Child component re-renders. Though the checkbox notifyProcess is nothing to do with the child component properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you to separate the WindowForm to a component it's seems that this is the problem.
when I use it as a component the memo start to work
I think is due to this is a function that return component so it's render it no matter what.

the solution:
move WindowForm out side of the component and create a new one with it and then call it and it will work fine

```
const WindowForm = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col span={12}>
            <label className={styles.labelWeight}> Name : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={selected.name}
              readOnly={true}
              className={styles.input}
            />
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <label className={styles.labelWeight}>Description : </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={selected.description}
              readOnly={true}
              className={styles.input}
            ></input>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="runImm"
              id="runImm"
              checked={isRunNow}
              onChange={handleSchedule}
            ></input>
            <label> Schedule as soon as possible</label>
          </Col>
          <Col span={12}>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="notifyProcess"
              id="notifyProcess"
              checked={isNotifyMe}
              onChange={handleNotify}
            ></input>
            <label> Notify me when this process ends</label>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <label>Submission Notes : </label>
            <textarea
              name="notes"
              id="notes"
              rows="4"
              cols="50"
              disabled={!isNotifyMe}
            ></textarea>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <Child isRunNow={isRunNow} />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

this component and his state to a new component and everything will start to work

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But still its not clear how moving the component outside worked. Any comments would be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: well I no sure myself I think it's because you send a function that rerender every time you rerender the component by change and value then it print the function again and again no matter the memo.
you  can try to use useCallBack maybe

Comment: @BNK after read a little bit it happend because you send a function that rerender everytime you change a state.
unlike usecallback that block those stuff if it's not match the dependencies